# I want a right arrow to change variable, but it will not work

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keycode

When I hit the right arrow, it does not change the variable. Here's my code:

```
var squareX = 10;
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    squareX += 10;
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm using the squareX variable to change the position of an object. The object does not move when I press the key. I could send the entirety of my code.

Comment: We don’t need the entirety of your code. We need just enough to reproduce the issue. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please do not add crucial details or unformatted code into comments. Instead [edit] your question.

Comment: This code just updates the variable. You don’t appear to redraw or update anything on the canvas after the variable has been updated.

Comment: I am updating the canvas, it was working properly if I just changed the variable manually, but this code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where’s your full code now? The code you show contains `squareX += 10;` as the _only_ statement in the event listener. This will update the variable, but it won’t do _anything_ in your canvas. Thus, you are _not_ updating the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use keydown instead of keypress:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
       squareX += 10;
    }
});
```

That did the trick for me!

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!